# Some error occurred when i change pem file on Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services

I lost the pem file in the awsec2 console, so I tried to access it after removing the volume and completing the pem file change,[image: the error code] and this error is appearing. How should we solve this?
I changed file on /mnt/home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_key and  /mnt/root/.ssh/authorized_key

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/4800344). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or press Ctrl+K, the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: I also recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: You should check that the **permissions** on the file make it only accessible to the user (eg `chmod 600`) and ensure that the file **owner** is the appropriate user (eg `chown ec2-user`).